# AppleWWDRCA certificate needed *at all* for OpenSSL signing?

Tags: ios, windows, air, openssl, certificate

Does the AppleWWDRCA.cer have any bearing on developing certificates using OpenSSL?  If so, what?  If not, what is it's use?

---

Edit:

I am using Windows.  I do not need an answer concerning Mac development.

So far, using OpenSSL, I have created development apps (signed, and with certificates), ad hoc apps for multiple developers (signed, and with certificates), and they all have worked just fine.  This is (probably) only a question about whether it is needed to put an app in Apple's App Store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the WWDR Certificate is only used to authorize your app for selling/integrating on the Apple App Store.

Public OpenSSL certificates are (generally) given to your application from an outside Certificate Authority and used by your users to authenticate (prove that your application is indeed what it claims to be) your application and encrypt the data they send in a SSL connection.  These can be generated entirely independently of your WWDR certificate.

Comment: Ok.  For the app on the app store submission version signing, do I need to incorporate the WWDR?

Comment: Yep.  The actual AppleWWDRCA.cer file you mentioned your "temporary" validation that will allow you to sign your app for testing as it goes through the review process.  Here's a more detailed guide to deploying you app on your iPhone for testing and then submitting it to the app store : http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/submitting-iphone-apps-to-the-apple-app-store-a-step-by-step-guide/

Comment: You are assuming I am on a Mac.  However, the main reason anyone uses OpenSSL instead of the Mac keychain is because they are using Windows.  Which is what I *am* using.

Comment: I see that your answer actually refers to certificates from OpenSSL, and *not* about developing the P12 file using Apple's certificates.  OpenSSL is an alternate to using Mac's keychain . . . ergo, it allows the development of apps using Windows or linux.

Comment: Ahh I see.  As far as I know, App Store submissions need to be signed using the keychain provided with XCode, unless you came up with a creative way to reverse engineer it...  In my (admittedly limited) experience with signing apps from Windows, I could only get OpenSSL signed apps to work on Jailbroken iPhones.  App Store submissions are the only reason I bought a Mac ;-)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explanation.  I see that back in October, they restricted their upload process, removing iTunes Connect submissions.  The question may now be moot, but can you let me know the process for signing them?  That is, was this using the App Store mobileprovision file (not ad hoc one)?  Did you happen to use the WWDC in that process?

Comment: Please note that though I am awarding the bonus here, this is not a complete answer.  I am still looking for an answer of how this all works.